# RavenDB questions: scope, querying, summary view

Tags: ravendb

I have an existing web site that is working with EF4 and SQL Server and hosted at AppHarbor. I need to make a stand-alone version that individuals can run locally with no Internet connection.  I am thinking of ripping out SQL and replace it with RavenDB. I think the data structure would lend itself well to this.

At a high level perspective, this is the structure

```
User
 - Elections
   - People
   - Locations
     - Ballots
       - Votes
```

Each user of the web site can create a number of "Elections".  Each election is totally self-contained, and is known to only the user who created it, and any "guest" users that they share it with.

Here are some questions that I haven't found answers to yet:

1. How do I isolate access to only the currently selected "election"?  Does each linq statement need to include a "where" clause to limit the scope to the election, or can I have the election "loaded" and work "inside" it?   Do I have to use `db.Query<Person>().Where(p=>p.Election==currentElection)` or can I do something like `election.Query<Person>()`?
2. Each Person has up to six fields: "Firstname", "LastName", "OtherNames", "ExtraInfo", etc. that I want to search in.  I need to frequently and quickly search through every person in an election looking for partial matches in all of these fields.  I would also like "soundex"-type matching.  Would an index be of use, or do I just use "brute force" and loop through all people?  If there are 50,000 people in an election, can I get sub-second responses?
3. How do I structure the documents so that each User can get and use a list of their Elections?  When viewing their list of elections, I want to display summary information about each election. Should that be "pre-stored" in the User object?  Or, when showing the listing, do I have to load parts of each Election to get the details (e.g. number of people, some attributes of the Election, etc.).

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you need to add the where clause. You can do `election.Query<Person>()`, if you add your own extension method.
2) You want to use an index. You'll get that speed and more. You might want to read about order search: http://ayende.com/blog/152833/orders-search-in-ravendb
3) You can query that, or store it, depending on too many factors.